# Cannot do anything at all with Bitcoin in my Blockchain.info wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, error

Blockchain support is useless, have had a couple of (small) transactions pending since November that will seemingly never get dropped or confirmed.

Whenever I try to send anything at all, from any device and with any fee, I get this:

```
× Close
BitcoindException(super=com.neemre.btcdcli4j.core.BitcoindException: Error #-26: 66: mempool min fee not met, code=-26)
```

Coinify sell orders don't work at all either so my "money" is literally irretrievable.

Comment: Well, there isn't much we can do for you regarding blockchain.info. But you can try to [export your private keys](http://bl4nkcode.info/bitcoin/how_to_export_blockchain_wallet_private_key#Steps) and import into Electrum, perhaps you might be able to spend from there.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of doing this. Do you have any idea what the error is on about though, never got it up until quite recently.

Comment: Since you have tried with higher fees, this smells like some kind of bug on their side.